# yaml multiple complex map keys as a struct

Tags: go, yaml

I want to unmarshal complex map key into struct:

**YAML**

```
unf:
    item_meta:
      source:
        ? id: "aa"
          name: "bb"
        : "some value"
```

**Struct**

```
type Source struct {
    ID     string `yaml:"id"`
    Name   string `yaml:"name"`
}
```

Everything works as expected until I add another key:

**YAML 2**

```
unf:
    item_meta:
      source:
        ? id: "012"
          name: "Bill"
        : "some value"
        ? id: "066"
          name: "Bob"
        : "another value"
```

I got an error

> "line xxx: mapping key "" already defined at line xxx"

I decided to use aliases:

**YAML 3**

```
unf:
    item_meta:
      aliases:
        - bill: &alias_bill
          id: "012"
          name: "Bill"
        - bob: &alias_bob
          id: "066"
          name: "Bob"
      source:
        ? *alias_bill
        : "some value"
        ? *alias_bob
          name: "Bob"
        : "another value"
```

It fixed the problem! **BUT** we use `hiera server` in our stack **AND** `hiera` returns contents of a config file already substituted so I end up with **YAML 2** version.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem? To config the `hiera server` is not an option.

Go [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/07gWst76a_f)

Comment: The discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/502) seems relevant.

Comment: @larsks let`s assume I can understand that non scalar keys are not supported. But how can you explain that it works with aliases?

Comment: I have no explanation, although I'm curious exactly what the structure looks like into which you're unmarshaling things.

Comment: @larsks type Source struct {
    ID     string `yaml:"id"`
    Name   string `yaml:"name"`
}

Comment: But that only matches the key. What does the larger structure look like? Especially for that second example?

Comment: @larsks I added a minimal reproducible example. You can check it if you will. https://go.dev/play/p/07gWst76a_f

Comment: I get errors with both example inputs (`mapping key "" already defined at line 6` with the version version, and `line 11: did not find expected key` with the second version).

Comment: @larsks your first comment helped. check my answer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution mostly was based on [this issue](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/502) @larsks

The idea was to find nodes with duplicate map keys and to create a custom value from value nodes of THE map node.

```
func fixYamlNode(node *yaml.Node) {
    if node.Kind == yaml.MappingNode {
        length := len(node.Content)

        for i := 0; i < length; i += 2 {
            nodes := make([]*yaml.Node, 0)
            nodes = append(nodes, node.Content[i])
            for j := i + 2; j < length; j += 2 {
                nj := node.Content[j]
                if nodes[0].Kind == nj.Kind && nodes[0].Value == nj.Value {
                    nodes = append(nodes, nj)
                }
            }
            if len(nodes) == 1 {
                continue
            }

            fillMapValue(nodes)
        }

        for i := 1; i < length; i += 2 {
            valueNode := node.Content[i]
            fixYamlNode(valueNode)
        }
    }
}

func fillMapValue(nodes []*yaml.Node) {
    for _, node := range nodes {
        length := len(node.Content)
        for i := 0; i < length; i += 2 {
            node.Value = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", node.Value, node.Content[i+1].Value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in go-yaml. See [these lines](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/00bbc0947ae889b9e480044dbc3bc3e3216a6a89/decode.go#L772-L778):

```golang
            ni := n.Content[i]
            for j := i + 2; j < l; j += 2 {
                nj := n.Content[j]
                if ni.Kind == nj.Kind && ni.Value == nj.Value {
                    d.terrors = append(d.terrors, fmt.Sprintf("line %d: mapping key %#v already defined at line %d", nj.Line, nj.Value, ni.Line))
                }
            }
```

This code checks for duplicate keys. For each key in the mapping (`ni`), it goes through all succeeding keys (`nj`) and checks whether they have the same *Kind* and the same *Value*. This is wrong, since `Value` is only set for scalar keys, so as soon as you have two keys that are mappings, this error fires even though the keys are different, because the code does not compare the key's content, only their Values (which will be the empty strings for non-scalar nodes).

I suggest you open an issue with go-yaml.

Comment: I think this is expected behavior. https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/751 But I may be wrong

Comment: @Bob The issue you linked is about allowing non-unique keys. I am talking about fixing the implementation of unique key detection. These are two very different things. As it stands, the implementation violates the YAML spec, which can hardly be expected behavior.